# Why does Typescript support WScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vbscript, wsh

I have installed Typescript just to have WScript intellisense in VScode.

And I got it. But whenever I compile a typescript `tsc myScript.ts` containing WScript method `WScript.Echo("hello world")`, it generates a <kbd>**.js**</kbd> file and evidently Nodejs does not interpret, saying that WScript has not been defined.  Of course, I don't want <kbd>**.js**</kbd>, I want <kbd>**.vbs**</kbd>...

Then Typescript doesn't support VBscript?!

As far as I know, WScript.exe | CScript.exe are Windows Script Host interpreters, created to break free from the web (server and browser), running in the operating system and auto-interpreted in files like <kbd>**.vbs**</kbd> or <kbd>**.wsf**</kbd>, or up to <kbd>JScript</kbd>, but it has nothing to do with Javascript. So why does the Typescript language server give WScript snippets if it can't compile or understand VBscript syntax?

In other words, **how do I leverage WScript intellisense for VBscript?** Will I always have to create a blank <kbd>**.ts**</kbd> file to see it expand the WScript methods, then copy and paste to pass it to my <kbd>**.vbs**</kbd>?

Comment: It's probably not possible to get it working as you want for VBScript. You may be better served by spending $59 for a lifetime license for [VBSEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com). It incudes intellisense for VBScript.

Comment: @LesFerch How does it work?

Comment: Best to see for yourself. The download is fully functional. Registering removes nag screen and delays.

Comment: @LesFerch Does this program expire?

Comment: Trial expiration? No, as stated, trial has nag screens and delays. License expiration? No, as stated, license is *lifetime*.

Comment: @LesFerch Your answer helped me. I'll be glad to mark your answer if you post it.

Comment: OK, I'll post the first comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not possible to get it working as you want for VBScript. You may be better served by spending $59 for a lifetime license for VBSEdit. It includes intellisense for VBScript.